# How can I add a custom date to the facebook timeline through graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I want to insert an entry to the new facebook timeline with a specific date (e.g., February 10, 2008), but not manually. I want to be able to do this using either the graph api or the new open-graph-beta. Is there a specific api call that can do this, or is there some other way.

***Update:***

I have figured out that in the api call you need to specify the start_time and end_time parameters as seen in the snippet below:

```
  FB.api('me/APP_NAMESPACE:ACTION?\
    start_time=904920127&\
    expires_in=905006527&\
    OBJECT_TYPE=URL&\
    access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN', 'post', function (response) {
      if (!response || response.error) {
        console.log(response);
      } else {
        alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
        console.log(response)
      }
  });
```

However the problem with this is that it just adds a specific year to your timeline and doesn't really add an entry to that particular timeline, i.e., when I click on the particular year I just created in my timeline app nothing shows up besides seeing the new year in my time line, in this case it's 1998.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you post an action via the Graph API, you can set 'start_time' and 'end_time' parameters.

This tells Facebook when the action occurred - and is useful for both backloading historical actions from a long time ago, or delayed actions like publishing offline listening activity.

Facebook represents actions on the timeline in the time period in which they occurred. Setting start_time in the past will make the activity appear in the past on their timeline.

Note that its against policy to publish 'fake' past actions - you must only publish actions that the user actually did in the past.

Comment: Simon thanks for your input, however this only partially answers the question. This still doesn't add any entry to your timeline, just adds the new year/month to your timeline with nothing in it

Comment: Thats probably a bug with Timeline - its still a beta product. However, you can't be sure that every action posted will appear on Timeline. FB makes an algorithmic judgement call about which actions, and in what form, should be shown on Timeline.

Comment: Simon, you're right this was definitely a bug and has since been fixed.  The code snippet above in my question now works great.

Comment: Simon, can you post a link where you found those infos? I'm wondering if you can set the start_time in the future to indicate that you are going to perform some action, like 'tomorrow I will quit my job' or so : ]

Comment: You can't set the start_time to be in the future - it's impossible to prediect the future ;-) If you want to model intention (I will go to) then the start time of the action represents when the user said they were going do do something. If you want to model the time they said they'll do it, you should make this a custom property of the action (or the object if thats more relevant)

Answer (score 1):

I think it may not be allowed, here's what you get for a start_time in the past :

{"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"The action you are trying to publish is invalid because the 'start_time' you provided of '1325770789' is more than '86400' seconds in the past."}}

Comment: This worked before, I can confirm that. But now Facebook decided to not let you date actions earlier than 1 day in the past.
And they say you have to be a 'select testing partner' of facebook to use the different start time function.
I don't know when I will be able to test this again.
Or when this feature will be out of beta.

More info about this [Facebook Bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/306026902781753/?browse=search_4f1e08c7becfa6314971065)