# Post to Timeline - with a date in the past

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-opengraph

(noob question)
Using the example.php that comes with the PHP SDK I can post to my timeline successfully.

I'd like though to be able to set the date, so I added:

```
:
:
 'created_time' => "2012-06-21T13:46:10+0000",
 'updated_time' => "2012-02-19T14:46:10+0000",
 'actions' => array(
             array(
                 'name' => 'Get Search',
                 'link' => 'http://www.google.com'
             )
     )
     );


     $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $attachment);
     ?>
     <?php endif ?>
```

But created_time is ignored, the post is always "NOW". I've searched around for a solution to this but found nothing. Am i doing something wrong, is it a typo, or just not possible like this?

Looking on the web I did find articles about placing "ACTIONS" in the past - e.g.: [How can I add a custom date to the facebook timeline through graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641055/how-can-i-add-a-custom-date-to-the-facebook-timeline-through-graph-api?rq=1)

Is that the (only?) way to go, create a "publish" action ,,. with start_time etc.? Any links to how to do this (in PHP?)

Comment: My guess (sans any investigation) is that this would simply not be possible.  `created_time` and `updated_time` are likely Read-Only attributes.

Comment: If you're looking at posting an activity conducted at a specific time (say in the past), why don't you use the Open Graph approach? So I baked a cake yesterday, etc...

Answer (score 3):

You can only [create actions in the past](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/publish-past-actions/), not Posts using the API. However, you can manually change the date of a post using the Activity Log - it doesn't look like this feature is available via the API yet.

Comment: Trying the change the date in the Activity Log - can't find the option to do this. Any hints?

Comment: In the dropdown i only see the options
Delete ..., 
Stop the App ..., 
Remove the App... and 
Mark as Spam ...

There is no "change date" option

Comment: Go to "Activity Log" and try changing it from there.

Comment: I get the same dropdown in timeline and in the activity log, top right hand side of entry, edit icon, CLICK, dropdown - No Change Date icon ;(

Comment: You probably can't change the date on whatever you are trying to change the date for. Try the same on something else and you should see the option (either with or without the date icon).

Comment: Erm... This question is about posts to the timeline via the example.php included with the facebook php sdk (as I think I made clear).

So what exactly do you mean by "whatever you are trying to change the date for". I think it should be clear. No?